# Swift SnapKit how to layout UIView with relative position

Tags: swift, snapkit

```
func setupPosition() {
        box.snp.makeConstraints{(make)->Void in
        make.edges.equalTo(view).inset(UIEdgeInsetsMake(64+20, 20, 250, 20))
        }

        textField.snp.makeConstraints{(make)->Void in
            make.edges.equalTo(box).inset(UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 150, 5))

        }

        stackBoxOne.snp.makeConstraints{(make)->Void in
                make.top.equalTo(box).offset(textField.frame.size.height)
                make.left.equalTo(box).offset(5)
                make.bottom.equalTo(box).offset(-90)
                make.right.equalTo(box).offset(-5)
        }
    }
```

I want to put the `stackBoxOne` under the `textField`. But the above code isn't working. How can I modify the code? Appreciate for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use `textField.frame` inside the `makeConstraints` closure because the views have not been layouted at that point. Because of that the height is `0` and `stackBoxOne` gets an offset of `0`.

To place a view underneath another view you connect its top constraint to the bottom constraint of the other view. So in your case:

```
stackBoxOne.snp.makeConstraints{(make)->Void in
     make.top.equalTo(textField.snp.bottom)
     make.left.equalTo(box).offset(5)
     make.bottom.equalTo(box).offset(-90)
     make.right.equalTo(box).offset(-5)
}
```

In addition to that you can also set the left and right constraint equal to the `textFields` left and right constraint like this:

```
stackBoxOne.snp.makeConstraints{(make)->Void in
    make.top.equalTo(textField.snp.bottom)
    make.left.right.equalTo(textField)
    make.bottom.equalTo(box).offset(-90)
}
```